# How do I setup an IoT Rule to write data to AWS Timestream

Tags: amazon-web-services

this should be something that works right out of the box, but I have been banging my head against the wall for 24 hours straight without getting anywhere.
All the "how toos" are stating the same procedures. I've tried to follow youtube videos like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tyz0XeeOc_M, but I'm still not able to get any data into Timestream.

I want a Thing from AWS IoT Core to write data to AWS Timestream. In Timestream, I have set up a database named test2 with a table called test2db. test2db has one partition key which is ${name}.
I have set up a Rule to write to test2db with SQL statement `SELECT * FROM 'esp32/pub'`. The Rule actions are configured with Dimension name = DIMENSION and Dimension value = ${name}.

In AWS IoT, I have tried to use MQTT test client to publish the following message to topic esp32/pub

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "device_ID": "bme280",
  "value": 29
}
```

when I inspect the test2db in Timestream, then it says that the table is empty.

`SELECT * FROM "test2"."test2db"`

Can you please help me debug?